# Dump the global variables in LLVM interpreter

Tags: c++, llvm-clang

I want to extend the code of Clang's C interpreter (see https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/examples/clang-interpreter) to dump the global variables in the program after

```
int Res = 255;
if (std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> Module = Act->takeModule())
    Res = Execute(std::move(Module), envp);
```

But I do not see a clear way of accessing the list of global variables in `ExecutionEngine` class (see http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#pub-methods).